# How to display gridview inside Multi view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, multiview

I want to display gridview inside multi view. I have tried the given below code. But it is not displaying on design. Help me to find a solution. Thank you.

Source:

```
 <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" >
 <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
 <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" BorderWidth="1" Width="973px" Height="595px">
 <asp:TableRow>
 <asp:TableCell>
 <br />
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Sl No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" />
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
 <br />                
 </asp:TableCell>
 </asp:TableRow>
 </asp:Table>
 </asp:View>
 </asp:MultiView>
```

Comment: Design view is not great when you have nested controls, does it display in the browser correctly?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use FindControl property and find the gridview in MultiView then bind your data to gridview